# Docker and Windows - Problems with SSH on default container

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

i'm new to Docker and i've just intalled Docker ToolBox 1.11.1 on my Windows 7 (64 bit).
 When running Quickstart Terminal i've got problems with creating default container.
After reading a bunch of forums i've invoked :

```
docker-machine rm -f default
docker-machine --debug create -d virtualbox default
```

But still without result. Full logs from last operation are :
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/117e302c047492170a6f0c7d4e79199a

They end up with phrase :
"(default) DBG | Error dialing TCP: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:49659: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I've have no idea how to fix that. Can someone help me ?

Comment: did the error happen after you tried to docker build?

Comment: I don't understand. Is 'docker build' needed in this situation ? I'm just trying to create and run default windows container witch is provided in boot2docker.iso.

Comment: try doing 'docker-machine ls' and see if a machine was created. cause its either the machine wasn't created in the first place or it was, but you can't connect to it.

Comment: On VirtualBox machine is created and running. But 'docker-machine --debug ls' fails and gives me :
 "(default) DBG | Error dialing TCP: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:22: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Answer (score 0):

In windows and Mac OS Docker run in a virtual machine. When you install Docker using the Docker Toolbox, it takes care of install Virtual Box, create a “default” virtual machine and configure it to run a Boot2Docker image.
With the command:

```
docker-machine rm -f default
```

you are removing this default VM. Then running the command:

```
docker-machine --debug create -d virtualbox default
```

you are creating a new VM called “default”, so you are not creating or starting any default windows container.

"Actively refused it" means that the host sent a reset instead of an ack when you tried to connect. Please, check the firewall or the proxy configuration because this is a communication problem.
Hope this can help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay and explanation. Unfortunately turning firewall off didn't helped. I've got no proxies configured so thats not the problem too.